# Unable to install nodemon on Windows for node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I am trying to install the latest version of the nodemon module for node.js, but when I do `npm install nodemon -g` I have the following errors :

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: chalk@'^0.4.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0"]
npm ERR! at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:682:10)
npm ERR! at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:597:10
npm ERR! at saved (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
npm ERR! at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com
```

Sometimes it's an error of `chalk@'^0.4.0'` or `configstore@^0.3.0` or `semver@2.2.1` (randomly).
Could you please indicate me how I can success to install nodemon ?
I am using node.js v.0.10.22, npm 1.2.14 under Windows 7 64 bits

Best
Loic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed to install the nodemon module simply by upgrading my version of node.js from 0.10.22 to 0.10.28.

Now it works !!!